# Unix app to write custom syntax to can check it

Tags: unix, customization

well the question is, exist some app or language/etc to write a custom syntax to can check files?

You know, when we works in different places, ppl and projects every one have differents rules to how write, code style and all that things, the idea its can check all this things because at least to me normally i forgot something.

Ideally some app without a heavy GUI, thinking maybe a terminal app, or editors like gedit, avoid plis apps like Eclipse and similars.

For now i need only check simple parts, if you can recommend both a simple/limited app and a complex/full app would be great.

Obvs, if exist a simple/full app, will be better.

Thx.

Comment: Only to write some expected features, can check: indents, spaces between functions, new lines between functions and other parts. This is the basic of basic things, ideally if we can do more (a complex ex, write the C syntax).

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is a program that rewrites a source code given a specific coding style, I advise you to take a look at GNU Indent.

If you want to do more complex operations like build an AST and work on it to add things, edit, check for existing dependencies or whatever, you'll want to use a tool like Flex/Bison, Clang, Pyrser, etc.

Comment: :O Thx!.for now i'll try Flex/Bison, with what i read about it seems it have what i need.